# Gulp within Visual Studio 2015 does not run angular2-template-loader

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, gulp, webpack

I'm trying to get a basic webpack-powered build working in VS2015 for an Angular 2 app. I'm using Gulp to trigger the webpack process (VS2015 has hooks that work well with gulp - webpack does all the heavy lifting in my case)

Here's the problem - when I use the VS2015 build process to trigger gulp (via 'after build' hook), the angular2-template-loader does not run. I'm expecting to see the templateUrl replaced with in-line mark-up, but it still references my template files. When I run gulp via command line, the angular2-template-loader seems to run and do its work.

Here's what I've tried:

- Running webpack straight from the command line gives me the desired result - which leads me to believe my webpack config is correct
- Running gulp straight from the command line gives me the desired result
- I've researched to see if there are any 'hidden' parameters VS uses that would cause different results as well as if VS was tied to a particular version of gulp. As far as I can tell, there are no hidden params or version dependencies.

For reference, here are my gulp and webpack configs as well as the bad output and expected output:
https://gist.github.com/scotmeiste/b9b91dcda13a896e771be0da5d89255c

On the output files, look at the templateUrl/template properties towards the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tldr:** VS2015 auto compiles TypeScript files by default, and this caused undesired results with the Gulp typescript build. Adding the following to the first `<PropretyGroup>` node in the project file corrected the issue:

`<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>`

**Details**

By default, Visual Studio will compile your TypeScript files, but **only** when you do a full rebuild. This explains why some of my changes in my TS file were not being propagated. The result of this was that my `app` directory would get filled with the output from the Visual Studio TS build, but not every time i would make a change.

When gulp would trigger the 2nd TypeScript build, I believe it would see the [bad] out put from the VS-triggered build and use those files, even though they were potentially out-of-date. They also didn't have the benefit of the `angular2-template-loader` process since VS only cares about running the TypeScript build.

**Solutions**

1. First solution is mentioned in the tldr - add the option to stop TypeScript Compilation.
2. Use another editor that will play nicer with gulp and webpack.
3. (untested) set the output in the TS config to match the output destination in your gulp file - not sure if this would resolve the issue with the `angular2-template-loader` not working.